# Can an OS X service present an interface?

Tags: macos, cocoa, service

What I'm trying to achieve: A service that will take a selection consisting of a number, present a window listing several currencies for the user to choose from and then replace the selection with the converted currency selected by the user.

The problem: I can get virtually everything to work. Service registers correctly and so on, and I can return text via the pasteboard to the calling application, but only when I set the pasteboard contents from the method called by the service. If I open a window and then call a method in the registered object to return the text then nothing happens.

In the method called by the service I instantiate a window controller and show the window. After the user clicks on the required option in the window I call a method in the registered object to set the text on the pasteboard. I'm not passing any text at the moment; I just set the pasteboard to a static piece of text. Everything works correctly, except nothing is inserted in the calling application. However, if I call the same method to set the pasteboard from within the method called by the service requestor then the text is correctly inserted in the calling application.

I've read everything I can find about services (including the Apple documentation), but they all deal only with services which either don't have a user interface or if they do, the interface is at the end of the process. For example, a selection might be a URL and is passed by the service to Safari, say to display the webpage. In those cases the interaction ends at the interface (Safari).

In my case, the interface is in the middle of the process and I need to get the results back to the original application. I originally tried setting the pasteboard in the window controller after the user makes their selection but that didn't work. I expected then that if I called back to the original object that registered the service and set the pasteboard there then it should work, but so far I haven't made progress with that approach despite trying various variations.

I guess my initial question is, "Is this something that I should be able to do?" In other words, can a service be used in the way I'm attempting? If the answer is yes, then where does my error lie?